# Why does isna()/isnull() function show different values compared to value_counts()?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am quite new to Machine Learning/Data science so I started doing my first Kaggle competition problem from here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques

I was cleaning the training dataset and filling some categorical features with mode values and after sometime I noticed something very strange. I filled the missing values of column 'MasVnrType' with mode and it turned out it filled all of them with None Values even though isna().sum() shows only 8 missing values. Is there some understanding that I'm lacking? [image: Here's the problem]

Answer (score 1):

By default, [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) has the parameter `dropna=True` that means that `None` values are not shown in the value count.

Try the code below. You should see the count of "real" `None` values. There should be a count of `8`.

```py
df['MasVnrType'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Why do you see `None 864`? That is probably because the the None values are actually `"None"`. They are `strings`. Since they are `strings` they are not counted in `isna()`, which only counts actual `None` values.

How to fix it? When cleaning the data, don't add `"None"` as a `string`, but rather add `None`.

Comment: Spot on! Completely agree.